# How to I set the scroll direction to be "non" natural for any new users created on a Lion machine?

Tags: user-account, defaults, macos

When a new user account is created on a Lion machine, a "helpful" dialog appears to describe "Natural" scrolling.

I want to set the scrolling to be "unnatural" for any new users created - is there a defaults setting for that?

Comment: To be honest, not giving the users the choice to try it out might not be the right approach. Every person in our office has moved to the new scrolling, and refuses to go back.

Comment: The intent is not to change for everyone on the machine -- just to set it so that the DEFAULT is set to 'non-natural' (really to help the PC people cope...). If an individual user want to change back, they can via system prefs.

Comment: Any ideas how to hide the 'introduction to scrolling' dialog?

Comment: I don't think it can be hidden. It's built into the wizard, and I am not sure if it can be removed or disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a `Terminal` window:

> `sudo defaults write /System/Library/User\ Template/Non_localized/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences  com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool false`

[Source](http://themacadmin.com/?p=494)