# Can I reverse the scroll direction of my mouse?

Tags: macos, mouse

I upgraded to OS X Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard and all of a sudden my scrolls in the browser window (chrome, Firefox etc) have reversed.

I need to scroll up to go down and vice-versa. Is there a way to change the direction ?

Comment: You should try to get used to the "natural" scrolling direction. I've found it to be considerably nicer than the old way.

Comment: I can't scroll on a computer with non "natural" anymore. It's so odd. Btw. This came with Lion.

Comment: Did you update from Lion? The direction reversal was introduced in Lion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I set the scroll direction to be "non" natural for any new users created on a Lion machine?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/how-to-i-set-the-scroll-direction-to-be-non-natural-for-any-new-users-created)

Comment: Let's leave both - this can cover people looking for 10.6 -> 10.8 and the other for 10.6 -> 10.7 upgrades. It's not logical to expect someone to know to ask about the previous version of the OS or when a change happened.

Comment: I highly recommend using scrolling on an iPad first. Now make your mouse / trackpad / whatever compatible with that muscle memory. If you do not it becomes crazy jarring switching between them. On tablets there is only one correct natural setting for scroll. In the old mouse world it was not clear and both were possible. We need to adapt now that one of those is shown to be wrong. I would say it is mandatory for trackpad; mouse-wheel if you use one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this in "System Preferences" -> "Mouse"

[image]

This change actually happened from [Snow Leopard to Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/how-to-i-set-the-scroll-direction-to-be-non-natural-for-any-new-users-created) with the introduction of Natural Scrolling to match iOS scrolling behavior where the motion is expected to work on the content - not the scroll indicator - as the two move in opposite directions.

Comment: Also possible from the terminal... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/how-to-i-set-the-scroll-direction-to-be-non-natural-for-any-new-users-created?rq=1

Comment: Cool, didn't know that

Answer (score 13):

The system preference for scroll direction is all-or-nothing and applies to every input device uniformly.  With some things, this just doesn't make sense.  If you want fine-grained control of which input devices scroll in which way (for example, if you want touchpads to use the "natural" scrolling while having the scroll wheel use traditional scrolling), try [ScrollReverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/).

Comment: Unf. for me, treats the Magic Mouse and conventional scrollwheel mouse both as "mouse"; had hoped I could set things up device by device. Otherwise a very nice find (+1, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to System Preferences icon on the Dock, then mouse in Hardware category, then scroll direction. The description could be different because I have it in Spanish that I am translating, but you need to un-check it anyway, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In **System Preferences**, go to **Mouse** and on the **Point & Click** tab ensure **Scroll direction: natural** is disabled

[image]

Comment: I see, I was confused by that option, I thought I was enabling scrolling instead of inverting the mouse.  Thanks.

Comment: Just remember, this way *is* the standard way now, on Macs.  Things change ;)