# Reverse Mouse wheel zooming in Sketch

Tags: mac, mouse

I am using a Logitech Mouse on my Mac and want to inverse the zoom direction inside Sketch (maybe in the whole system - until now I only zoomed in Sketch). How can that be done? I am scrolling using the mouse wheel. Thanks!

Note: I am talking about zooming, not about scrolling (the later one can easily be changed in the Mac OS options).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I reverse the scroll direction of my mouse?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60732/can-i-reverse-the-scroll-direction-of-my-mouse)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe - Logitech have their own control panel for their mice. Rather clumsy for some things, but this is one task it can do on a per app basis, though not for just zoom, you'd have to flip the scroll direction entirely.

Comment: Please note that my only issue is zoom. I already changed scrolling in the Mac OS settings. There's no option to reverse zoom direction though.

Answer (score 1):

Logitech Options can reverse the scroll direction on a per app basis - however it reverses the entire scroll action, not just the zoom direction.

Top right, select the App you want to affect, then select Standard or Natural in the Scroll Direction drop menu.

[image]

If you have an older [or just less darned awkward than my MX2] mouse that doesn't use Logitech Options, you may be able to achieve better results with something like [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) which can do most tasks on a per app basis, including Zoom…

[image]

Until recently, SteerMouse & Logitech Options would fight each other badly, yet SteerMouse couldn't see all of the buttons on my MX2 properly, so I've been stuck with Options for a while & cannot test SteerMouse in this instance.
*Edit:* Tested again 19 Sept 2019 - they still fight each other & SteerMouse can't use the Gesture button properly, so I'm still on Options.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. The SteerMouse looks very promising, I will test it. I recently uninstalled the Logitech Options in preference for another tool. Note that the Logitech Options allow to change scrolling, that's what I've already changed in the Mac OS settings. SteerMouse looks promising from the screenshot :-)